# How to split a pandas dataframe on the frequency of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am interested in separating this data frame into 20 smaller dataframes based on the frequency of entries in column B. B has numerical entries, some of these are repeated several times, as can be seen below.

```
 A (index)              B (Column of interest) 
    0                              1
    1                              2
    2                              2
    3                              2  
    4                              3
   ...                            ... 
  25643                          5238
  25644                          5238 
  25645                          5238
  25646                          5238
  25647                          5238
```

I am looking to have one data frame for each frequency: 1-10, 11-20, 21-30,...., 191-200.
Meaning, 1-10 dataframe contains all the entries from B that appear between 1 and 10 times throughout this dataframe. Similarly, the 11-20 dataframe contains all the entries that appear 11 and 20 times throughout the dataframe.

In the end, I should have 20 dataframes, all of which split this main dataframe.

All I've been able to do is find the distinct number of entries in my desired entries from Column B that correspond to these freeuqncies using the following code:

```
   df.loc[(df['B'] > 0) & (df['B'] < 11)]
   df.loc[(df['B'] > 10) & (df['B'] < 21)]
                    ...
   df.loc[df['B'] > 190) & (df['B'] < 201)
```

I have been thinking of using the `groupby()` function, however, I haven't found a way to group the column entries based on frequency.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Count the occurrence of each value in the dataframe, bin the frequency ranges in groups of 10, and then create a `dict` of `DataFrames` for each range.

  1. Use [`pandas.Series.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to create a count column in `df`, which will convey the frequency of the value in the `B` column.

     - `df.B.map(df.groupby('B')['B'].count())` also works, but isn't necessary.
  2. Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to bin the frequency ranges

     - `labels` are used, as they are easier to use as `dict` keys

       - Without using `labels`, the `dict` keys will be an `Interval`, like `[Interval(10, 20, closed='right')`, which is cumbersome.
  3. Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with a [`dict-comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to create a `dict` of `DataFrames` based on the bin label.

     - The bin labels will be the `dict` keys
     - The `bins` column is categorical, so `.groupby` will create a group for each label, even if the group is empty, therefore use [`pandas.DataFrame.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html), so only non-empty groups will be added to the `dict` of `DataFrames`.
     - Replace `g: dfg` with `g: pd.DataFrame(dfg.B)` to have only column `B` in the `dict`.

       - Use `dfg.reset_index(drop=True)` or `pd.DataFrame(dfg.B).reset_index(drop=True)` to remove the original index.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup test dataframe
np.random.seed(365)
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': np.random.randint(5238, size=(200000))})

# add a counts column to the dataframe
df['counts'] = df.B.map(df.B.value_counts())

# create a bins column for the frequency range
bins = range(0, 201, 10)
labels = range(10, 201, 10)
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df.counts, bins=bins, right=True, labels=labels)

# display(df.head())
      B  counts bins
0  2740      37   40
1  4897      41   50
2  4955      45   50
3   428      31   40
4   226      34   40

# create a dict of dataframes for the non-empty bins
dfd = {g: dfg for g, dfg in df.groupby('bins') if not dfg.empty}

# print dict keys
dfd.keys()
[out]:
dict_keys([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])

# display(dfd[20].head())
          B  counts bins
5350   4986      19   20
5646   4952      20   20
11232  3728      19   20
11707  2819      20   20
13547  3728      19   20
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a perfect solution!